# How to convert timezone offset to another format

Tags: go, timezone

I have a timestamp without timezone information . I need to add to it the timezone offset in the "+02:00" format. So in the following code how to convert offset variable to a "+02:00" string so as to have a proper RFC3339 time?

```
func main() {
    zone, offset := time.Now().Zone()
    fmt.Println("zone :", zone)
    fmt.Println("offset :", offset )
    logtimestamp := "2020-11-14 05:53:40,103"
    logtimestamp = strings.Split(logtimestamp, ",")[0]
    logtimestampFields := strings.Fields(logtimestamp)
    if len(logtimestampFields) > 1 {
        logtimestamp = logtimestampFields[0] + "T" + logtimestampFields[1] + "+02:00" //replace "+02:00" with proper offset here
    }
    
    formattedTime, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, logtimestamp)
    fmt.Println("formatted timestamp " + formattedTime.Format(time.RFC3339))
}
```

Comment: Could you please accept my answer if it helped you? It'll help the community!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should help. I've commented the code for better understanding.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // Get the timezone
    zone, offset := time.Now().Zone()
    // Get the location
    var loc = time.FixedZone(zone, offset)
    // Reference format: Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006
    t, err := time.ParseInLocation("2006-01-02 15:04:05", "2020-11-14 05:53:40", loc)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    // Print the timestamp in RFC3339 format
    fmt.Println(t.Format(time.RFC3339))
}
```